# enquiry about MediaPlayer.setDatasource(URL);

Tags: java, android, stream, media-player

I'm a Beginner in android programming and I want to programming mp3 app to call some mp3 files from URL, so when I show "Media Player" in android developer I put the URL in the `setDataSource` and it's work fine, but the problem is the Activity take a lot of time to display it and in the sometimes app will be crashed. This is the part of my code :

```
    file_url = Mp3_Linkes[num];

    //Set Source
    try {   
        mp.setDataSource(file_url); 
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Source Error !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    //Prepare
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Prepare Error !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    //Start
    mp.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity is blocking because you are calling prepare on your Main Thread (UI thread)

Instead You can use prepareAsynch and OnPreparedListener to start specially when loading from remote source:

code :

```
try {

     mp.setDataSource(file_url);

    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {

                player.start();
        }
     });
    mp.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: Great code ,,, but I have problem to , Some file (not all) don't play all the time it's such as playing in first seconds only and after this  :S  the player is Stop ,,, Why ?!

Comment: Oh No :( the seekbar don't work !! and when I change it the player is stop and replay from the beginning :(

Comment: The seekbar fixed ,,, can you help me about first comment ?!

Comment: Please use google to find a solution for these issue.

For example take a look at this tutorial http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/